# How do I get Vidalia Tor to work on 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, package-management, vidalia

A.S.: Complete Linux noob here.

I'm trying to install Vidalia from the Software Centre, and apparently everyone says that it doesn't work on 14.04.
However someone posts a link to a [fix package](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/utopic/universe/base/vidalia)

I manage to install the package with dpkg, but when I try to start Tor from Vidalia, it gives me this error:

> Vidalia was unable to start Tor. Check your settings to ensure the
>   correct name and location of your Tor executable is specified.

The location appears to be `/usr/sbin/tor`

Answer (score 0):

Just follow up these steps

1. Open up `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.vidalia` file with root permissions. For this you can run `sudo gedit /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.vidalia` in a Terminal.
2. Add this line `/usr/bin/tor Ux,` anywhere inside the `/usr/bin/vidalia {...}` block. Place of this line in that block does not matter.
3. Run `sudo apparmor_parser --replace /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.vidalia` in a Terminal.

Okay, now you're done!